# Get Checkbox Value Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display an error message or success message depending whether a textbox value is empty or has a value.

Comment: What do you mean by "null"? Do you mean empty? When should this happen? On `blur`? On some form submit event?

Comment: Please provide us with some of your code so we can better answer your question.

Comment: Well, i misinterpreted the term "not using jquery" and created a jsfiddle example with plain JavaScript - If some one cares: http://jsfiddle.net/SLZzc/

Comment: <form  id="demo-form">
<textarea   cols="40" rows="10" id="remarks" placeholder="Remarks (enter courier number and courier service provider for confirmed redemptions, enter reason for rejected redemptions)"></textarea>
<input type="text"  id="Amount_For_Investor" placeholder="Amount For Investor" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input  type="text"  id="courier_charges" placeholder="Courier Charges"/>
<input value="Confirm" type="submit" id="confirm" />
<button  id="reject">Reject</button>
</form>

Comment: i want check the textbox values when user clicks the confirm button

Answer (score 1):

This is not much of a well-formed question, but despite that - take a look at jQuery validator ( http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ ) This plugin does all the error checking and warning that you could want. If it is more than you need - well, you'll have to give more info in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are looking for..

```
$("input:text").each(function()
{

    var element=$(this);
    if(!element.val())
    {
      element.css({background:"yellow", border:"3px red solid"});
    }

});
```

Hook in this function whenever you want to verify the textboxes are empty or not like form submit.. look at jquery events for more details.

Answer (score 0):

i assume your textbox id txtbox

```
 First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id ="txtbox"/><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id ="submitid"/>

$("#submitid").click(function(){
   if ($("#txtbox").val().length > 0) {
    alert("it is empty")
    return false;
}  
})
```